# Intuition behind formula probability of default in risk management

Tags: correlation, intuition, risk

I am new in risk management and i would appreciate if someone could clarify me the formuala for correction of probability of default for some type of loaner in stress scenaria.

it looks like this
$PD = PD_0+(PD_0*(\frac{max-min}{min})* \text{correlation})$

where max and min are maximum and minimum of some given risk factor in some period of time. correlation is correlation coefficient between this risk factor and some fund index that reflects given type of loaner.

I do not understand intuition behind formula. When correlation coefficient is multiplied by some value, like in this case (max-min)/min, what do we get?

Comment: Can you provide reference for this formula?

Comment: it is written in some internal document in bank, so i can not upload it.